# Изображение непонятно растягиваеться в редакторе Unity

Tags: unity3d

в общем с того ничего началась вот такая вот фигня, меня если честно от нее тошнит очень... Помогите пожалуйста [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите размер экрана в редакторе и Canvas в инспекторе.

Comment: Похоже на камеру с настройкой проекции "ортографическая" вместо "перспективная"

Comment: а как найти размеры канваса и экрана? я просто юнити меньше 2х недель учу.

Comment: Размер экрана показывается в окне `Game`

Comment: А нажимая на объект `Canvas` увидите его параметры в окне `Inspector`

Comment: всем спасибо, я уже нашел где была проблема.Кому интересно там на окне сверху в правом углу полупрозрачная кнопочка есть...